# Throwing a C++ exception after an inline-asm jump

Tags: c++, assembly, exception

I have some odd self modifying code, but at the root of it is a pretty simple problem:  I want to be able to execute a `jmp` (or a `call`) and then from that arbitrary point throw an exception and have it caught by the try/catch block that contained the `jmp`/`call`.

But when I do this (in gcc 4.4.1 x86_64) the exception results in a `terminate()` as it would if the exception was thrown from outside of a try/catch.  I don't really see how this is different than throwing an exception from inside of some far-flung library, yet it obviously is because it just doesn't work.

**How can I execute a `jmp` or `call` but still throw an exception back to the original try/catch?  Why doesn't this try/catch continue to handle these exceptions as it would if the function was called normally?**

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

void thrower()
{
    cout << "Inside thrower" << endl;
    throw runtime_error("some exception");
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Top of main" << endl;  

    try {
        asm volatile (
            "jmp *%0" // same thing happens with a call instead of a jmp
            :
            : "r"((long)thrower)
            :
        );
    } catch (exception &e) {
        cout << "Caught : " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Bottom of main" << endl << endl;
}
```

The expected output:

```
Top of main 
Inside thrower 
Caught : some exception
Bottom of main
```

The actual output:

```
Top of main
Inside thrower
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  some exception
Aborted
```

Comment: Originally I asked a similar question in the context of signal handlers in linux. That really just clouded the issue, so I deleted that one and asked this much more simplified version. The whole signal handler thing was just masking my real problem.

Comment: There are roughly two different ways to implement exception handling. One is to decorate the code and call sites so as to push context around everywhere, the other is to index the call and return points so that an exception handler can look up where to go. Either way, inline asm is missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **gcc 4.4.7**(and above) on **x86-64 linux**, with **dwarf** exception handle mechanism (which might be the default one), I have a way to work this out.

Suppose your inline assembly code is a function `inline_add`. It'll call another function `add`, which might throw a exception. Here's code:

```
extern "C" int add(int a, int b) {
    throw "in add";
}

int inline_add(int a, int b) {
    int r = 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movl %1, %%edi\n\t"
        "movl %2, %%esi\n\t"
        "call add\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %0\n\t"
        :"=r"(r)
        :"r"(a), "r"(b)
        :"%eax"
    );
    return r;
}
```

If you call `inline_add` like this:

```
try {
    inline_add(1, 1);
} catch (...) {
    std::cout << "in catch" << std::endl;
}
```

it'll crash, because gcc doesn't provide the exception frame for `inline_add`. When it comes to a exception, it has to crach. (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html) for the 'Compatibility with C')

So we need to fake a exception frame for it, but it would be hard to hack with gcc assembly, we just use functions with proper exception frame to surround it

we define a function like this:

```
void build_exception_frame(bool b) {
    if (b) {
        throw 0;
    }
}
```

and call `inline_add` like this:

```
try {
    inline_add(1, 1);
    build_exception_frame(false);
} catch (...) {
    std::cout << "in catch" << std::endl;
}
```

and it just works.

`build_exception_frame` should come after the call, or it won't work

Further more, to prevent optimiziong gcc might take on `build_exception_frame`, we need to add this:

```
void build_exception_frame(bool b) __attribute__((optimize("O0")));
```

You can check the assembly code that gcc generates to verify the code.

It seems that gcc provide exception frame for the whole `try`/`catch`, as long as there's one function might throw, and position matters.

Need to see how gcc works on that later.

If any knows about that, please be kind enough to let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at how your implementation handles exceptions? It involves looking up PC addresses in tables to figure out what the program was doing the particular spot that threw, and what all callers were doing. At least on Mac OS X GCC.

The only other system I've looked at, Metrowerks Codewarrior for Mac (way back when) used a similar system, albeit somewhat more transparent. The compiler can transparently insert functions for any kind of exception context change.

You don't have a prayer of making this portable.

Comment: Interesting...  But if I embed a legitimate, working call to "thrower()" inside the same try/catch, the inline-asm version still doesn't work, which it sounds like you're saying it should.  I guess the exception handler could be looking at the address of the call itself, which is not one it knows about.  This is the most promising answer so far....

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the assembly code generated by gcc if your try {} block simply contained a function call? I'm pretty sure that the C++ compiler does more than just a jump at that point, since it needs to be able to back-trace the stack when an exception occurs.

Your code might be workable if you were able to mimic the steps that gcc takes when structuring the function call.

***Update:*** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87220/how-does-gcc-implement-stack-unrolling-for-c-exceptions-on-linux) may provide more information. In particular, the throwing and catching portion of the Itanium ABI may be of use: [link](http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html#imp-throw)

Comment: That question doesn't provide much more information. My feeble attempt to understand exception handling (on Mac OS X) led me into some odd `libunwind` code, for which I couldn't find the open source. It was written in C++(!) and had Apple naming conventions. Point being, it isn't strictly functionality of GCC. Look in the GCC source and you'll see that it depends on OS supplied libunwind.

Comment: Nope it looks like the asm is just a call to the function (I put inline-asm comments around the call, and there are no instructions between the comments except the call itself).

Comment: @SoapBox: You need to compare the exception dispatch tables to see what the functions that *are* inserted at `try{` and `throw` operate on.

Answer (score 1):

Once you do the inline assembly, you have implementation defined behavior (7.4/1).

You should try and set up a stack frame; details are platform specific and I don't know how to do it on x86_64.