# Catching Exception From ASM code in C++

Tags: c++, exception, assembly

I have some odd code which needs to call a throwing function in an `asm` block and be able to catch the exception thrown. My code looks something like this:

```
// Throwing Function
void throwing() __asm__("throwing");
void throwing() {
    throw "abc";
}

// Assembly function which calls throwing()
void asm_call() {
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "call throwing\n"
    );
}

// Main calls the assembly function in a try block
int main() {
    try {
        asm_call();
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "caught..." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to get the exception to be caught by main; it always simply terminates when it reaches the `throw "abc";` line. I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642385/throwing-a-c-exception-after-an-inline-asm-jump), and I tried the top answer but it did not work for me. Is it possible to catch the exception which is thrown in the `asm_call`?

I'm using x64 Linux with g++ 6.3.0.

Comment: Since you are inserting assembler, there is no stack-unwinding information available for that part of the call stack, so the stack-unwinding code just errors out. I have no clue as to what needs to be done to get the stack-unwinding code properly skip over your asm `call`, but I'd strongly suggest that you just wrap the `throwing()` function into a `non_throwing_callthrough()` wrapper, that catches the exception and returns an error code.

Comment: You can't easily use `call` from inline asm in x86-64 Linux [because it clobbers the red-zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm).  The only safe workaround is to `add $-128, %rsp` first.  When you compile with optimizations enabled, code like that can and will break when `asm_call` is inlined.

Comment: Or maybe this doesn't apply if you call a function that always throws, but then you have a different problem: you've written an `asm()` statement where execution enters but leaves somewhere else, and you didn't use `asm goto` to tell the compiler about it.  The compiler might decide to leave something until *after* the `asm volatile`, but then it never happens.  (Using a `"memory"` clobber can help prevent that).